# Getting the source IP address of incoming connection

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

As we know TCP connection is established using 3-way handshake protocol .

We can get peername in these two ways .

```
1. a) connfd = accept(sfd,&addr,&addrlen);
   b) int getpeername(connfd,&addr,&addrlen); 
2. a) connfd = accept(sfd,&addr,&addrlen);
      here struct addr has information about client
```

Let's say we have used select over socket descriptor(s) . Then if some one requested for the connection then socket descriptor(s) must be set . So we can use now above methods to get client address .

Is there a way to get the client address before accepting the connection
since as we  already know that some has requested for this connection.

Application:
Let's say we don't want to allow client coming from address i.j.k.l to i.j.l.m then we can use this method to save some resources.

OS: Ubuntu 
P/Language : C/C++.

Edit:
As people have suggest firewall is there , yes it's there but it will work for below example
`We  are running`n`servers on a machine each server should exclude some IP addresses . Then how to use firewall here ?`

Comment: That's what firewalls are for.

Comment: We don't know someone has requested a connection, or who, until `accept()` returns.

Comment: Referring your edit: What? I do not understand this?

Comment: "*Then how to use firewall here?*" start by reading its documentation. Anyways this might become another question, different from this one here.

Comment: @alk what you didn't understand ?

Comment: "*I have just mention one application where we can use this application . Also i want to implement this program .*" Which "*application[s?]*"? Which "*program*"?

Comment: @alk oh! sorry . I have removed this line from edit .

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. Does this problem require any C++ functionality to understand? Then tag it as C, because you're only calling C functions.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This code doesn't . But if we include C++ functionality then we have to still use the same  library function .

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the client address before accepting the connection

No.

At least not from the client's perspective.

> Let's we don't want to allow client coming from address i.j.k.l to i.j.l.m

For such use cases firewall systems are around.

Comment: No we don't want to using firewall .

Comment: Then you need to accept, check the source and in case you do not want it, drop the connection. @sonukumar

Comment: @sonukumar  Then you will have to call accept() and close the connection as long as you're on linux. (Other systems (e.g. windows) can allow oyu to get notified before the 3 way handshake is completed)

Comment: @nos if we use your methodology then there is  no resource saving .Also it's a workaround .

Comment: @sonukumar you can write kernel module using netfilter then you can get connection in 3-way-handshake and then close connection if you prefer but again in this method you use firewall.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani If we have more than one socket which filters different IP addresses then  we have write module with different IP-RANGE as well server program .

Comment: sonu what you basically want is not to use a firewall, but to create one of your own. A bad one.

Comment: @sonukumar: You can get this functionality out of the box with most firewall implementations. RTFM `man iptables` for example. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck yes i want .

Comment: @alk some time to learn something we need to reinvent the wheel .